# Customizing Angular8 date picker arrow (top and bottom arrow)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I like to customize the Angular 8 date picker with top and bottom arrows. The default one is left and right arrow. How do I customize it.

[Angular 8 date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlaAe.png)

Answer (score 0):

lets say selector of that button is .myButton. Use host selector to override the default style if you want for a specific component like

```
:host>>>.myButton {
   background-color: white;
}
```

or specify this in your global styles.css

```
.myButton {
      background-color: white !important;
}
```